# how to output the OpenCV image out of the callback function?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am subscribing a videostream of compressed image and i knew how to convert it into OpenCV image and was able to show it already. But i want to output(like return value) the OpenCV image from the callback function.How should I do it?

---

```
void imageCallback_L(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr&msg)
     {
            try
            {
            cv::imshow("imgCallBack",cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(msg->data),1));
            cv::waitKey(1);
            ROS_INFO("receving fisheye_left_image");
            }
            catch(cv_bridge::Exception&e)
            {
            ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s",e.what());
            }   
    }
    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"CompressedImage");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber image_sub;
    std::string image_topic="/sensors/camera/fisheye_left/image_raw/compressed";
    image_sub=nh.subscribe(image_topic,10,imageCallback_L);

    while (ros::ok())
    {
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388751/how-to-output-the-opencv-image-out-of-the-callback-function?/) by [luzhenzheng1990](https://answers.ros.org/users/87300/luzhenzheng1990/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-15**:
If you check your cpu usage, you will find that this code is using 100% of the cpu. You need to limit how many times per second that while loop executes, and you do that by adding a short sleep inside your while loop. Or simply replace the entire loop with a `ros::spin();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The method `cv::imdecode` returns a `cv::Mat` object so you just need to store the output in a `cv::Mat` object that is not in the callback's scope :

```
cv::Mat img;
void imageCallback_L(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr&msg)
{
    try
    {
        img = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(msg->data),1)
        cv::imshow("imgCallBack",img);
        cv::waitKey(1);
        ROS_INFO("receving fisheye_left_image");
    }
    catch(cv_bridge::Exception&e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s",e.what());
    }   
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2021-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1